# How does SSAS populate the LEVEL_TYPE information in MDSCHEMA_LEVELS rowset

Tags: ssas, mdx, xmla, dmv

I ran the following DMV query on SSAS.

```
SELECT
 [HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME],
 [LEVEL_NAME],
 [LEVEL_NUMBER],
 [LEVEL_CARDINALITY],
 [LEVEL_TYPE]
from $system.mdschema_levels 
where [DIMENSION_UNIQUE_NAME] = '[DATE]'
 AND [CUBE_NAME] = 'Adventure Works'
 AND [LEVEL_NAME] <> '(All)'.
```

I get a lot of unexpected LEVEL_TYPES[image]

I wanted to understand what do the LEVEL_TYPE like 4289, 4578, 4385, 4759 signify? Are they computed algorithmically or is they a documentation resource one can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

These Level_TYPE are determined the "Type" property of the dimension attribute that you set in dimension design window of your SSAS project. In case if you set the Type to regular you get 0 else , if you select from one of the types present you get its identifier. The interesting bit is if the HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME has a attribute hierarchy, it returns the identifier for the attribute hierarchy, if HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME has user hierarchy, then the identifier is returned for the LEVEL_NAME's base attribute. For example in the result below, take a look at the two rows that return 68 in LEVEL_TYPE, the first row is being reported as attribute hierarchy, the second as user hierarchy's level(Notice the Level_Number 3 and the difference between the HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME and LEVEL_NAME)

[image]

Edit: Specific type details

4289: type Date,
4578: type QuaterOfYear,
4385: type HalfYearOfYear,
4759: type WeekOfYear

Comment: @rshetye does it help?

Comment: I am more curious about the level numbers like the details of levels like 4289, 4578, 4385, 4759

Comment: @rshetye specific details added

Comment: could you share the source of the mapping? The list was just a few samples, I am more interested behind the complete list.

Comment: @rshetye the source of the mapping is my answer above. Kindly go through it again.let me Know if any issues.

Comment: would you know if the mapping is mentioned in some Microsoft documentation?

Comment: @rshetye I have not come across the exact mapping defination document. Would you like to share what are you trying to achive

Comment: My team is developing a database engine which simulates SSAS behavior